# Headless Selenium Node.JS

Tags: node.js, macos, selenium-webdriver

I cannot import Chrome Options to use Selenium in headless mode on Node JS (OS X).

My code is

```
  import { Builder, Browser, By, Key, until } from 'selenium-webdriver';

  let driver = await new Builder()
    .forBrowser(Browser.CHROME)
    .build();
  await driver.get(url);
```

That's work just fine. But then I tried to add
`import chrome from 'selenium-webdriver/chrome';`

And that's an error `Cannot find module. Did you mean to import selenium-webdriver/chrome.js?`

How to get it works in headless mode?

Comment: @Philippe Nope, It does not work this way

Answer (score 0):

```js
const Chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import { Builder, Browser, By, Key, until } from 'selenium-webdriver';
import chrome from 'selenium-webdriver';
  
let driver = await new Builder()
    .forBrowser(Browser.CHROME)
    .build();
await driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```